# How to save a submitted a form value in json without calling any service or backend?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

I have chain of forms in my page. I have to submit the form and it needed to be updated into a json and need to retrieve from it. Is that possible to construct like this without calling any service or backend.

Comment: It sounds like you need some kind of client-side storage mechanism either cookies or local/session storage in the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what your goal is, your can simply 'grab' your form in jQuery:

```
var form = $('#my-form');
```

And then serialize the contents to json using:

```
var serialized = form.serialize();
```

See https://api.jquery.com/serialize/ for more information on `serialization`.

However if you're looking into `server-side processing`, you'll have to use `ajax` anyway.

See https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ for more information on `ajax`.